# Why char array return a codpoint after Convert.ToInt32?

Tags: arrays, string, type-conversion, char, converters

Need to know a reason of this behaviour of method Convert.ToInt32()

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long a = 12345678912345;
            string str = a.ToString();


            char[] chars = str.ToCharArray(5, 7);

            //result is: 6 7 8 9 1 2 3

            int[] ints= new int[chars.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
            {
                ints[i] = Convert.ToInt32(chars[i]);
            }

            //result is: 54 55 56 57 49 50 51

            int[] arr = new int[str.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);
            }

            // result is: 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 49 50 51 52 53 
        }
```

So, why when I try to convert char to int I get unicode decimal code of number?
And what I should do if I want to get an integer number?

I expected to got int format of number